# How to make simple animation using ngAnimate

Tags: angularjs, animation

I am not able to understand how the `ngAnimate` works exactly. here is my doubt.

1) `ngAnimate` - only works on `directives`?

2) how to make `ng-animate` work without the `directive`

3) Any of above way, how to add call back after `animation` complete?

Because i see all the `animation` examples only with `directives`.

I have a small demo here, any one help me to animation both without `directive` and with `directive` approach to simply adding a class name as `fade'?

my CODE:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="content" ng-controller="count">
        <h1 ng-click="animate()">Click ME</h1>
        <h2>Let me Fade</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="content" ng-controller="count">
        <h1 ng-click="animate()">Click ME</h1>
        <h2>Let me Fade</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo to update](http://jsfiddle.net/f4xthn86/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able to understand how the ngAnimate works exactly. here is
>   my doubt.

`ngAnimate` is a module that provides support for animations in angular apps. There are two ways to make use of animations when `ngAnimate` is used: by using *CSS* and *JavaScript*. *For CSS based animations, angularjs adds a class `ng-enter/ng-leave` whenever an element is shown/removed from 'view'*. You simply need to play with these classes to make the animation work!

**Prerequisite:**

- You would need to add the library for `angular-animate`

  ```
  <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-animate.js">
  </script>
  ```
- and include ngAnimate as the dependency in your `myApp` module.

  ```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
  ```

> 1) ngAnimate - only works on directives?

Yes. You cannot use ngAnimate without directive.

According to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate), following directives are "animation aware":

- `ngRepeat`, `ngView`, `ngInclude`, `ngSwitch`, `ngIf`, `ngClass`,
- `ngShow`, `ngHide`, `ngModel`, `ngMessages` and `ngMessage`

> 2) how to make ng-animate work without the directive

You cannot!. Remember, even `ng-click` is a directive

> 3) Any of above way, how to add call back after animation complete?

Yes, You can add a callback after the animation is complete using the [$animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate) service(which would usually be done in a custom directive) and use `$animate.leave(element, [options]);`

Have a look at this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5r9tBmqCdYO9st7MlKUj?p=preview) for triggering events after the animation ends.

Finally, here is the updated [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ufF0FwIUFKKhuuepFzgS?p=preview) you mentioned in question.

You may toggle a `flag` to true/false with each click on `<h1>` and make content inside `<h2>` hide/show based on flag.

```
  <div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
      <div class="content" ng-controller="count">
          <h1 ng-click="animate()">Click ME</h1>
          <h2 ng-if="flag" class="fade">Let me Fade</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Also, you'd need to handle fade-effect with css

```
.fade.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}    
.fade.ng-leave {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:1;
}
.fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: for my scenario how to implement the `callback` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
<div class="content" ng-controller="count">
    <h1 ng-click="animate()">Click ME</h1>
    <h2 ng-if="clicked" class="animate-if">Let me Fade</h2>

</div>
```

I added a variable named **clicked** which is set to **true** or **false** to *animate* the Let me Fade Text

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('count', function($scope) {
     $scope.clicked=false;   
    $scope.animate = function () {
    $scope.clicked=!$scope.clicked;     
    }
});
```

In this JS file upon clicking the **click me button** the variable clicked is set to **true** or **false** .

```
**

 h2.fade {
   opacity : 0;
   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.animate-enter, .animate-leave {
transition: 500ms ease-in all;
position: relative;
display: block;
} 
.animate-enter.animate-enter-active, .animate-leave {
left: 0;
}
.animate-leave.animate-leave-active, .animate-enter {
left: 500px;
}
```

**

Here in  the css file i added css for the class animate which acts upon clicked variable if the variable is **true** it goes for *animate-enter-active*
otherwise it goes for *leave-active*